# Not able add free Ignite clearDB to Heroku app

Tags: heroku, cleardb

I am not able to add free Ignite clearDB to my Heroku app. It asked for to give credit card information.

[image]

Terminal:

[image: see the message]

Not sure how to add it not providing the credit card information. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, only Postgres can be configured without an "Account Verification" through Heroku. See: [Account Verification](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#when-is-verification-required)

> When is verification required? You must verify your account if you, or
>   collaborators of your app, want to:
>
> - Use more than one dyno in the app.
> - Add any add-on to the app, even if the add-on is free. The only exceptions to this are the free plans for the Heroku Postgres and
>     Heroku Connect add-ons, which can be used without verification.
> - Add a custom domain to the app.
> - Receive the transfer of an app that has paid resources.
> - Exceed default one-off dyno limits on the app.
> - Have more than 5 apps at a time. Verified accounts may have up to 100 apps.

Try changing your database to Postgres if you don't want to give up credit card info. Just be sure to note the slight syntax differences.

Comment: Cool! If you find a way around giving out a credit card tell me!

Comment: sure, I will share with you if I find out anything. Please share your mail id. Are you using Heroku in your application? I am new to Heroku. @Alicia